# Finding Hidden Wordpress Login Page

Tags: wordpress

I have all the files of a Wordpress site downloaded to my computer.
This Wordpress site was developed by someone else.
I only have a copy since the owner would like me to help with it since her original developer is being difficult.

My issue now is that I can't find the admin login page.
Typically one would just add /admin or /login to get to that page then all that is needed is the password and username.

In this case, I can't even get to the first step of finding the login page.
Since I have all the files of the Wordpress site, I believe there must be a way to find out how to access the login page.

How does one go about finding out where the login page is hidden in a Wordpress site if one has all the files of a Wordpress site???

Thank you....

Comment: Have you tried asking the owner?

Comment: The real owner does not know the password and how it is configured since she is not a developer.  Her developer is being difficult so we are not sure how cooperative her developer will be if she asks for the password, username and where to find the login page within the wp site.  That's why I have to find the backdoor in since I have access to the server and downloaded all the wp files of the site.

Comment: A list of the filenames could help but /wp-admin or /wp-login.php is the default login page for WordPress.

Comment: add wp-admin not /admin

Answer (score 1):

Well, from my own experience, most of the time it is being renamed via a security plugin.

So i would go first into wp-content/plugins directory check what plugins are being used, if you see any plugin for security you may be in the right direction.

For example, if you use rename Login page feature with "All In One WP Security & Firewall plugin" it's going to be stored into the database ; assuming you have database access, you may try to find it by querying something like :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE wp_options.option_name LIKE '%login_page%' OR wp_options.option_value LIKE '%login_page%';
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

My best hack to find a hidden admin and perfectly working is really.Concept is to simulate a validation url just after your register a new account.

Eg : We are looking for admin for www.domain.tld

Type a link as : https://www.domain.tld/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=**UzH1JcD59iBmbkjfsK8O**&login=**admin**

You can replace **key string** and **login value** by what you want,it does not matter.

When you put this link on your browser, you will be automatically redirected to good path of admin.